# Redefine layout block in child view with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have my layout looking like this :

```
    <!doctype html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>My title</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "general" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "libs/jquery-1.5.1.min" %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">

      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <% if flash[:notice] %>
              <% if flash[:notice].kind_of?(Array) %>
                 <% flash[:notice].each do |id, value| %>
                    <p><%= id =%> <%= value =%> </p>
                 <% end %>
              <% else %>
                <p><%= flash[:notice] =%></p>
              <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <% if flash[:error] %>
          <p class="error"><%= flash[:error] %></p>
        <% end %>
        <!-- more content -->
        <div id="principal">

        <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
        <%= render 'layouts/banner' %>
            <%= yield %>
        <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

My problem is this line :

```
<%= render 'layouts/banner' %>
```

I have a banner in the top of my website. And i want to change it on each page. How can i overwrite this render from my index.html.erb view of my controller for example?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`content_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for). For instance:

**layout**

```
<%= content_for :banner %>
```

**view**

```
<% content_for :banner do %>
  <h1>Banner for ThisParticularView!</h1>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

In your layout:

```
<%= content_for?(:banner) ? yield(:banner) : render 'layouts/banner' %>
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= content_for :banner do %>
  banner code...
<% end %>
```

is the way closest to what you have now. However, I recommend just passing a local to the banner partial and using that on every page, like so:

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/banner', :locals => { :image_path => 'images/banner1.png' } %>
```

And then your 'banner' partial (it should be a partial, `_banner.html.erb`):

```
<%= image_tag(image_path) %>
```

You can even make it into a helper to save you a few keystrokes:

```
def banner(image_path='images/banner1.png')
  render :partial => 'layouts/banner', :locals => { :image_path => image_path }
end
```

And then:

```
<%= banner 'images/banner5.png' %>
```

This also makes it easier to provide a default value to eliminate the possibility of Nil errors from your view, should you somehow forget to provide an image path to the `banner` helper.

Comment: No need to call yield twice and check for `empty?`.  There's a `content_for?` predicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can

1 Use custom logic within the layouts/banner view

2 utilize [content_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html)

```
# Somewhere deep inside
<% content_for :banner do %>
   <!-- banner code -->
<% end %>

# In layout
<%= content_for :banner %>
```

3 Render custom banner file

```
# In controller
@file = "some_banner_file
# In layout
render @file
```